# Правка отклоняется духом из-за конфликта с последующей правкой

Tags: поддержка, предложение, дух-сообщества, правки

Иногда произвожу правки вопросов от других участников сообщества: редактирую текст, добавляю метки, меняю оформление. Сейчас я делаю это так, чтобы не менять основную мысль сообщения.

Суть моих правок — исправление очевидных проблем в вопросе: орфография, выделение кода. Не все правки, разумеется, достойны публикации. Однако, заметил не очень приятную особенность внесения правок.

Например, пытаясь внести изменения в сообщение [SQL “вычитание” из count по условию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696749/sql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-count-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E) столкнулся с тем, что мою правку уже не в первый раз отклоняет [Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Причиной отклонения моей [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/184416) стало то, что автор вопроса сам внёс изменения в сообщение уже после того, как я предложил правку.

Причём это не единичный случай, когда именно [Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) отклоняет правку из-за конфликта с последующей. Для примера [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/181035) или [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/178417).

У меня скорее вопрос: как такое получается? Как я понял, очередь на правки могут пропускать сами авторы сообщения, а также пользователи с репутацией больше 2к.

Я согласен, что пользователь с репутацией в 2к имеет полное право обойти очередь и сделать свою правку, отклонив предыдущие (хотя для это существуют проверки с пунктом "Отклонить и править" или "Принять и править"), но почему эту очередь могут обходить новые пользователи? Я не зря за пример взял тему [SQL “вычитание” из count по условию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696749/sql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-count-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E). Если посмотреть историю правок, то можно увидеть, что автор внёс свою правку, которая не просто не улучшила качество сообщения, но ухудшила его. Впоследствии она была исправлена уже другим участником.

Минус для меня только один — +1 отклонённая правка в статистику. Но суть не в этом. Это сообщение — вопрос и предложение. Так задумано? Если да, на сколько это рационально? Может, стоит это всё же исправить?

---

P.S. Я не нашёл похожих сообщений на Мете, но если таковые есть — простите.

Comment: Думаю, что так и задумано. Это вопрос автора, и позволять автору дополнять собственный вопрос деталями -- крайне приоритетная вещь, предлагаемые правки не должны этому мешать.

Comment: @D-side Это правильно. Но, думаю что автору должен "пасть" выбор. Он сам должен решить, отклонить или принять мою правку. Возможно, что, когда я редактировал сообщение, другой редактор (пользователь или автор сообщения) вносил правки одновременно со мной. Я предложил правку раньше. Когда второй участник опубликовал правку, ему просто не выдало сообщения, что уже внесена правка и её стоит рассмотреть. Я только понимаю, что такое работает если правку делают принудительно (без проверки (автором сообщения или участником с реп.>2к)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автор всегда имеет приоритет над остальными. Будет странно заставлять автора ждать в очереди, если кто-то другой исправил сообщение. Новичок впадёт в ступор, если не сможет отправить свою правку, поэтому не надо его пугать. Остальные же могут разобраться. Так и задумано.

Участники с высокой репой, напротив, не могут влезть посередине и должны дождаться прохождения проверки чужой правки, правда они могут сами проголосовать за или против правки в очереди на общих основаниях. Будет странно давать им право отвергать чужую правку. (Есть исключения: если участник с высокой репой начал править, потом в очереди возникает чужая правка, а затем этот участник отправляет правку, то правка из очереди аналогичным образом будет отклонена. Также есть обходные пути, позволяющие воспользоваться этой дырой, чтобы проигнорировать чужую правку в очереди.)

Система использует оптимистичные блокировки, потому что один текст вдвоём правят не настолько часто, а пессимистичные блокировки были бы слишком обременительны и мешали бы работе ещё больше. В этой ситуации побеждает первый. Для участников с низкой репой победа в гонке даётся только после прохождения правкой очереди.

### Что делать?

Во-первых, не беспокойтесь о последствиях. Хотя отклонённые правки в больших количествах обычно ведут к автоматическим ограничениям возможности править, отклонённые конфликтом правки не считаются против вас.

Во-вторых, если вашу правку отклонили по той или иной причине, то можно отправить её снова, смержив изменения. Если автор-новичок вытворяет с текстом что-то странное, то можно написать в комментариях совет, чтобы помочь разобраться, или предложить свою помощь с правками в явной форме.

P. S. Не знаю, как вы исправляете орфографию, если вы умудрились написать "откланяется" в заголовке... Не говоря об остальном.

Comment: Ошибки бывают у всех. На то я и человек. Но я не сужу никого, а просто исправляю то, что вижу. То, что попадается на глаза. За ответ – спасибо. Согласен с логикой. Главное, чтобы эти отклонения влияли только на статистику.

Comment: Правка откланялась и ушла за кулисы.